# How to force Tomcat doesn't write data (like logs, temp, ets) to its own root folder?

Tags: java, tomcat, desktop-application

I'd like to create a desktop standalone application from my Java/Spring web application. I created MSI-installer that copy all required files to **C:\Program Files (x86)\App**. But tomcat doesn't have permission and can't write to its own folder. How I can configure tomcat so it would write **all** app-specific data to other folder? I wouldn't like to install my app to **C:\App** or user dir.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\App\tomcat\logs\catalina.2016-06-18.log (Access denied)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the environment variable `CATALINA_BASE` to another directory in your tomcat start script you can configure Tomcat to read/put the working data, configuration and stuff from/to another location. If `CATALINA_BASE` is set, Tomcat will use the folders `%CATALINA_BASE%/bin`, `%CATALINA_BASE%/conf`, `%CATALINA_BASE%/logs`, `%CATALINA_BASE%/temp`, etc. for the current instance of Tomcat. This is described in more detail in the *Advanced Configuration - Multiple Tomcat Instances* section of the RUNNING.txt file in Tomcat's root folder.

If you are planning to ship Tomcat with your application and put all Tomcat files to some user choosable folder you should set `CATALINA_HOME` to this folder. Tomcat will then use this folder as base directory for everything.

However I think, as you mentioned to ship a standalone application based on Spring, you should seriously take a look at [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). This will allow you to ship a single fat jar containing **all** of your application's dependencies (including Tomcat). And this application can simply be started by executing the jar file.

---

If it's just about the log and temp files, you can set the Java system properties `java.util.logging.config.file` and `java.io.tmpdir` in the setenv.bat file under `%CATALINA_BASE%/bin` to make Tomcat use a custom logging configuration and a different temp dir, respectively. That is the file would look something like this:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=file:///c:/path/to/log/config.properties"
set CATALINA_OPTS="%CATALINA_OPTS% -Djava.io.tmpdir=c:/path/to/temp/dir"
```

Answer (score 0):

Find and update all occurrences of `"$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out` to custom path in `catalina.sh` script.